# Migrating from Sequelize to Prisma, PrismaClient crashing server with no logs

Tags: docker, sequelize.js, prisma

I am trying to migrate from Sequelize to Prisma

I have followed [this guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/migrate-to-prisma/migrate-from-sequelize) very closely.

It successfully pulled the existing schema into my schema.prisma file, and I made the suggested changes for **createdAt**, **updatedAt** and **Model names/mapping** in the guide.

Prisma Studio is working in the browser, using `npx prisma studio`. I am able to view my existing data.

Once I import and try to use PrismaClient, the server instantly crashes with no logs other than:

> 2023-05-19 17:49:59.659 UTC [923] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

The following is how I am invoking PrismaClient, which is causing the crash. If I comment it out and stop using it, the crash stops occuring.

`import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"`

`const prisma = new PrismaClient()`

I have looked high and low on Google, found [this discussion](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12684), but removing **node_modules** folder and doing `npm install` is not working for me. Neither is `npx prisma generate` as suggested in the first reply.

I am using Docker for my node and postgres servers, which may be adding certain complexity to my troubleshooting, but I don't believe it's causing my issue.. Since Prisma Studio is successfully connecting to the db and pulling data. The issue is occuring with Prisma Client.

I am fairly familiar with the Sequelize workflow, but brand new to Prisma and the migration workflow, so this may be the gray area causing my issues and lack of understanding. Any help is greatly appreciated.